# Regexp Question - Negating a captured character

Tags: regex, perl

I'm looking for a regular expression that allows for either single-quoted or double-quoted strings, and allows the opposite quote character within the string. For example, the following would both be legal strings:
"hello 'there' world"
'hello "there" world'

The regexp I'm using uses negative lookahead and is as follows:

```
(['"])(?:(?!\1).)*\1
```

This would work I think, but what about if the language didn't support negative lookahead. Is there any other way to do this? Without alternation?

EDIT:

I know I can use alternation. This was more of just a hypothetical question. Say I had 20 different characters in the initial character class. I wouldn't want to write out 20 different alternations. I'm trying to actually negate the captured character, without using lookahead, lookbehind, or alternation.

Comment: Do you intend to allow backslash escaped quotes as well? They are good at complicating matters :P

Comment: Considering the answer given below, wouldn't it just be a slight tweak using alternation? The order of the alternation is crucial so that the dot doesn't consume the backslash, leaving the captured character to match:
(['"])(\\\1|.)*?\1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is actually much simpler than you may have realized.  You don't really need the negative look-ahead.  What you want to do is a non-greedy (or lazy) match like this:

```
(['"]).*?\1
```

The `?` character after the `.*` is the important part.  It says, consume the minimum possible characters before hitting the next part of the regex.  So, you get either kind of quote, and then you go after 0-M characters until you encounter a character matching whichever quote you first ran into.  You can learn more about greedy matching vs. non-greedy [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) and [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).

Comment: thank you! this is what I was looking for. totally forgot about lazy quantifiers. well now I feel stupid

Comment: No need to feel bad - regex's are powerful, but complicated.  It's hard to keep it all in your head.  That's what SO.com is for.

Comment: The regex can be slightly improved by removing the expensive match all `.` by using - `(['"])[^\1]*?\1`

Comment: @Peter Ajtai, no it can't; backreferences aren't allowed in character classes.  That class gives you any character but \001 aka chr(1).

Comment: @ysth - Whoops. I just realized that. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Sure:

```
'([^']*)'|"([^"]*)"
```

On a successful match, the `$+` variable will hold the contents of whichever alternate matched.

Answer (score 1):

In the general case, regexps are not really the answer. You might be interested in something like [Text::ParseWords](http://search.cpan.org/~chorny/Text-ParseWords-3.27/), which tokenizes text, accounting for nested quotes, backslashed quotes, backslashed spaces, and other oddities.